# Liquibase script for MYSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, liquibase

I have a liquibase xml script. When I run it on Postgres I don't face any problem but when I run it for MYSQL it gives error when the structure is of the following type:-

```
<insert tableName="user_table">
        <column name="id" valueComputed="(select max(id)+1 from user_table)"/>
        <column name="name" value="someName"/>
    </insert>
```

When the above script is executed for MYSQL it gives error:-

> *You can't specify target table 'user_table' for update in FROM clause.*

I found a solution to this by using alias like this :-

```
<insert tableName="user_table">
   <column name="id" valueComputed="(select max(id)+1 from (Select * from  user_table) t)" />
   <column name="name" value="someName"/>
</insert>
```

But there are thousands of entries like this. Is there any generic way of doing it so that I don't have to change the script at so many places. Thanks.

Comment: XML processor? like a Python script with `expat` or a SAX XML processor or whatever your preferred tool is?

Comment: "*You can't specify target table 'user_table' for update in FROM clause.*" - that's one of the limitations in MySQL that you have to live with. It has nothing to do with Liquibase.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach would be to just update the XML, either with an simple XML parser program or even a regexp search and replace in your text editor.

Alternately, you can override the standard liquibase logic to look for that particular valueComputed pattern and replace it. There are a couple points you could make the change at:

- Override the liquibase.parser.core.xml.XMLCHangeLogSAXParser class, probably the parseToNode() method to search through the generated ParsedNode for valueComputed nodes
- Override the liquibase.change.core.InsertDataChange class generateStatements() method or addColumn() method to replace valueComputed fields.

See http://liquibase.org/extensions for more info on writing extensions.